# Como puedo hacer setvalue de un select options en Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular5

Este es mi html:

```
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 mt-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control" id="operator-groups" formControlName="operators">
                            <option disabled selected value>Seleccione</option>
                            <option *ngFor="let operator of operators; let i = index;">{{operator.desc}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Este es mi component:

```
this._operatorgroups.index().subscribe(res => {
      let operators = <OperatorGroups[]>res;
      this.operators  = operators;
      this.registerForm.controls['operators'].setValue(res[1].desc);
    });
```

Gracias!

Comment: En tu HTML tienes la primera opción como selected...

Comment: La primera option es para dar una explicacion sobre que es

Comment: Lo que quieres es inicializar el valor del select, no? Pareces que lo estás haciendo en dos sitios

Answer (score 1):

La forma de trabajar con select es usando ngValue:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 mt-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="operator-groups" formControlName="operators">
            <option disabled selected value>Seleccione</option>
            <option *ngFor="let operator of operators" [ngValue]="operator">{{operator.desc}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

De este modo, el value en el form control no usa ningún atributo de operator, usa todo el objeto operator, lo que puede ser muy cómodo:

```
this._operatorgroups.index().subscribe((operators :OperatorGroups[]) => {

  this.operators  = operators;
  this.registerForm.controls['operators'].setValue(operators[1]);
});
```