# ¿Cómo evitar tener 2 opciones repetidas en un <select>?

Tags: angular, html-select, ngfor

En el `ngOnOnit` relleno los campos de mi formulario de la siguiente manera:

```js
form: FormGroup;
authorList$: Observable<Author[]>;
book = {} as Book;  array
autor = {} as Author;

 ngOnInit(): void {
    // obteniendo el id de viene en la url
    this.activeRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.idBook_url = params.id;
      console.log('el id de book recibido es: ' + this.idBook_url);
      this.bookService.getBookById(this.idBook_url)
      .subscribe(book => {
        console.log('los valores del libro son: ' + book[0].id_author);
        this.authorService.getAuthorById(book[0].id_author.toString())
        .subscribe(
          res => {
            this.autor.id_author = res.id_author;
            this.autor.name = res.name;
            console.log('id autor: ' + this.autor.id_author, ' nombre: ' + this.autor.name);
          },
          err => console.error(err)
        );
    // relleno los campos del formulario
        this.form.patchValue(book[0]);
      });
    });
    this.authorList$ = this.authorService.getAuthors();
 
  }

buildForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      year: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.max(this.year)]],
      author: ['', [Validators.required]],
      category: ['', [Validators.required]],
      editorial: ['', [Validators.required]],
      description: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(2500)]],
      quantity: ['', [Validators.required]],
      price: [0, [Validators.required]],
      image: [''],
      state: [true]
    });
  }
```

el problema que tengo es que en el `<select>` tengo 2 opciones repetidas, la opcion que esta por defecto y la opcion que esta en lista `authorList$`:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay alguna forma de preguntar por ejemplo con un `*ngIf` que si el dato que esta por defecto es igual al que esta en  `authorList$`, no lo muestre al desplegar el `<select>`? o alguna otra forma de evitar las opciones repetidas? soy nuevo en `Angular`.

Aca el `<select>` del formulario.

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Autor</label>
    <select [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="book.id_author" class="form-control"
        FormControlName="author" (change)="captureIdAutor($event)" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>5){this.size=5;}"
        onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;">
        <option [value]="autor.id_author" [selected]="autor.name">{{  autor.name }}</option>
        <option *ngFor="let author of authorList$ | async" [value]="author.id_author">
            {{author.name}}
        </option>
    </select>
    <div *ngIf="form.get('author').invalid && form.dirty" class="error">
        <p *ngIf="form.get('author').hasError('invalid')">Este campo es obligatorio!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No mandas a llamar tus datos con un query?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como puedo hacer setvalue de un select options en Angular 7?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/217050/como-puedo-hacer-setvalue-de-un-select-options-en-angular-7)

Comment: Gracias @Pablo lozano utilice en [ngValue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la funcion `pipe` se utiliza para hacer modificaciones al stream. Existen varios operadores que puedes utilizar como: `filter, map, take` etc. Para modificar los datos antes de llegar a su destino final.

Primero se crea un array de los puros ids (id_author) dentro de un objeto `Set` que no permite valores repetidos (en este punto eliminamos los ids repetidos) el segundo map itera los ids del `Set` y los busca en el array principal `authorList`

```
this.authorList$ = this.authorService.getAuthors().pipe(
    map(authorList => {            
        return Array.from(new Set(authorList.map(a => a.id_author)))
        .map(id => {
            return authorList.find(a => a.id_author=== id)
       })
    })
);

<option *ngFor="let author of authorList$ | async" [value]="author.id_author">
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Set

Comment: Hola @Abel Valdez gracias por responder, por lo que entiendo de tu codigo,que lo estas hacendo es: declarar un array "arrayToIterate", despues al inciar el componente le estas agregando a ese array lo que tiene authorList$, y despues recorres con un ngFor lo que tiene arrayToIterate, que seria lo mismo que tiene authorList$ no?, pero de esa forma no estaria evitando las opciones repetidas en el select.

Comment: Exacto, la clase Set() se utiliza para este tipo de casos para cuando no quieres repetir el contenido en el array

Comment: tambien puedes modificar directamente el stream utilizando un pipe y un map cuando  haces la llamada al API

Comment: al hacer esto:  this.authorList$ = this.authorService.getAuthors()
    .subscribe(authorlist => {
      this.arrayToIterate = new Set(authorlist);
   }); angular me indica un error en this.aithorList$ diciendo que Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<Author[]>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more

Comment: no necesitas hacer esta asignacion " this.authorList$ " ya que esa varible es un observable no una suscripción.

solo hazlo asi his.authorService.getAuthors() .subscribe(authorlist => { this.arrayToIterate = new Set(authorlist); });

Comment: Actualice la respuesta, pera que la verifiques es una mejor solucion

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda!, funciona!

Comment: Perfecto! y entendiste como funciona?

Comment: Entiendo que haces una copia en el array quitando el dato repetido, pero no entiendo el map, me mareó, soy novato en Angular y todo esto de hacer un pipe y adentro de ese pipe un map se me hace dificil.

Comment: El pipe se utiliza para hacer modificaciones al stream filter, maps, take hay muchos operadores que se pueden utilizar para modificar los datos antes de llegar a su destino final. 

primero se crea un array de los puros id_author dentro de una clase Set que no permite valores repetidos (en este punto eliminamos los ids repetidos)
el segundo map itera los ids del Set y los busca en el array principal "authorList"

Comment: Gracias, ahora si entiendo, muy buena tu explicacion!

Answer (score 0):

```js
checkExistValue( id ){
  if(this.authorList$.find( autor => author.id_author == id )) return false;
  return true;
}
```

```html
<option *ngIf="checkExistValue(autor.id_author)" [value]="autor.id_author" [selected]="autor.name">{{  autor.name }}</option>
```

podrías hacer algo así